# My website flashes white between page loads and is doing poorly in search engines

Tags: css

I don't know if my CSS code is simply in bad shape, if I've done something wrong, or if I've not done something that I should be doing. But my website flashes white when navigating between pages. Additionally, it's doing poorly with the search engines despite every effort to have it ranked higher.

I'm so new to this I hope someone can help me in very simple terms.

Comment: Your HTML is suspect. You have started a second `<html>` block inside your first `<head>`, then started another `<head>` block before terminating both. It looks like you've used a page generator for some of this too. Go back and sort out your HTML, which should fix your flashing, and might help your page rankings too.

Comment: I'm not seeing a flash of white on latest chrome (29.x).  One suggestion though - specify a size for your image(s).  The browser has to relayout once it has the image dimensions and that I do see on your site. You also have a query param on the main logo - the browser is going to download that every time.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick responses.  I'm glad that there are problems which stand out for someone to see.  BUT...  as mentioned, I'm new.  I have no idea where <head> is.  I know of course where the css code is and <header> is listed a zillion times, but where do I find the reference to <head> that you mentioned?  Same question for where do I find places to specify a size for images?  Finally, I have no idea what a query param is.  These must be obvious to someone smarter than me, but would you mind taking that extra step to walk me like a first grader through all this?  thanks so much

Comment: do you know your html as well? or just css?

Comment: Frankly, there are so many problems with your page, ranging from the simply odd to the plain wrong. It's not going to be possible to walk through this and fix it all on-line. Get yourself a good book on HTML and study it, then look at it yourself. Come back with specific questions. Or pay someone to fix it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't fix that white flash, that's just your page loading, if you have a decent browser it'll cache the background and it'll flash less you probably have chache turned off on your browser which is why you notice it so much, change your background to white, so it's not so annoying that would be my advice. You can how ever load new content and replace it on the same page with jQuery Ajax and you won't have and page loads and that flash. And good page rank takes years to earn.